# How do I count the number of records in a group using Active Record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a list of files and a list of words that are in these files.
The foreign_key is the field `filenum`.
A file can have multiple occurances of a word, so wordtable can have a number of entries of filetable for one word with different word positions.

My Active Record classes are:

```
class File1 < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = :filetable
  self.primary_key = :FileNum
  belongs_to :word
end

class Word < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = :wordtable
  self.primary_key = :fileNum
  has_one :file1, foreign_key: :filenum, primary_key: :filenum
end
```

My query is:

```
query = 'ole'
Word.where(['name LIKE ?', "%#{query}%"]).group(:fileNum).each do |word, occurences|
  printf "%-24s %12s %12s\n" %  [word.name, word.file1.FilePath, occurences]
end
```

Here a subset of my current results:

```
ole       C:\Users\user\ruby\_nakijken\stringbuilder_list_properties.rb             
boolean   C:\Users\user\ruby\_nakijken\s_pinger.rb             
console   C:\Users\user\ruby\_nakijken\s_transition.rb
ole       C:\Users\user\ruby\_nakijken\save_outlook_message.rb   
...
```

The query works except for the total of occurences. I would like to have the number of occurences of that word in that file.
How should I do that?

For the moment, id do it it a somewhat ugly way

```
query = 'require'
name, filenum, count, filepath = '', 0, 0, ''

Word.where(['name LIKE ?', "%#{query}%"]).group(:name, :filenum, :position).each do |word|
  if filenum == 0
    name, filenum, count, filepath = word.name, word.filenum, 1, word.file1.FilePath
  elsif name == word.name && filenum == word.filenum
    count += 1
  else
    printf "%-24s %12s (%s)\n" %  [name, filepath, count]
    name, filenum, count, filepath = word.name, word.filenum, 1, word.file1.FilePath
  end
end
if filenum == 0
  puts "'#{query}' not found"
else
  printf "%-24s %12s (%s)\n" %  [name, filepath, count]
end
```

Comment: thnx for the edit Tin Man but I wonder: do you ever sleep :)

Comment: Shouldn't your relation be "File has many words" instead of "File belongs to word" ?

Comment: you have `:FileNum, :filenum, :fileNum` - it is kind of confusing to read the code - it is not apparent what you are grouping by - the `Word` primary key?

Comment: i use existing tables from another program (text finding), in filetable the primary key is FileNum, in wordtable it is filenum, srr can't help that, the grouping should be on the filenum field, and that works, but i need the numer of occurences of that word in that file

Comment: @Vimsha: i search for a word, so i only need the relationship in one direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/count):

> If `count` is used with `group`, it returns a `Hash` whose keys
>   represent the aggregated column, and the values are the respective
>   amounts:
>
> ```
> Person.group(:city).count
> # => { 'Rome' => 5, 'Paris' => 3 }
> ```

It seems you should add `count` to your query:

```
query = 'ole'
Word.where(['name LIKE ?', "%#{query}%"]).group(:fileNum).count.each do |fileNum, occurences|
  # ...
end
```

---

For your current solution (as my solution did not seem to work), I can suggest a little cleaner version, using `group_by`:

```
grouped_words = Word.where(['name LIKE ?', "%#{query}%"]).group(:name, :filenum, :position)
grouped_words.group_by { |group| [group.name, group.filenum] }.each do |(name, _), words|
  printf "%-24s %12s (%s)\n" %  [name, words.first.file1.FilePath, words.count]
end
```

Comment: I read and tried that before asking Uri, but then you just get an integer (undefined method `name' for 1:Fixnum), not a result set of records

Comment: shouldn't you also group by `:name` to have `name` method? `Word.where(['name LIKE ?', "%#{query}%"]).group(:name, :fileNum).count`...

Comment: if i do i get an array of arrays with the name and count, but i lost my reference to the wordrecord and so also to the filerecord, guess i will have to keep count in the inner loop..

Comment: i have a working solution (see question edit) but i'm not happy with it, seems to me this shouldn't be necessary

Comment: @peter - have you tried `.group(:name, :file1).count`? anyway, see my update for an improvement suggestion for your current solution

Comment: I just did, that gives error SQLException: no such column: file1, i also tried your improved version and it works fine and is way shorter, thanks, i eliminated the first .group(:name, :filenum, :position) to make it even shorter

Comment: any idea how i could load eagerly this way ? now there is a select for every file SELECT  "filetable".* FROM "filetable"  WHERE "filetable"."filenum" = ? LIMIT 1  [[nil, 883]]

Comment: association.rb:107:in `association_key_type': undefined method `type' for nil:NilClass